# Can somebody explain this named group regex?

Tags: regex

In the Sublime Text package [CheckBounce](https://github.com/phyllisstein/CheckBounce) (package that implements OSX built-in spellchecker in ST) an option exists to define per syntax the text that should be checked.
Here's the explanation in the settings file:

```
// Optionally define regular expressions to set the scope in which spelling should
// be checked. The regex should define a named group called "checktext", which the
// package will use to extract the text to check. For example, a regex to skip the
// preamble in a LaTeX document might look like this:
//      (?s)(?<=\\begin\{document\})(?P<checktext>.*)
// This expression would only match text between HTML tags:
//      (\<\w+\>)(?P<checktext>.*)(\</\w+\>)
// Each one must appear in the dictionary below with the key set to the syntax name
// and the value set to the regular expression. Remember to double your backslashes.
```

So how do the two regular expressions mentioned work? I don't understand how they match the preamble and the HTML tags.

An explanation would help me to write my own regex to exclude all the LaTeX specific syntax like `\centering` and `\cref`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help get you started
Note that these are very general regex's.

```
 ## Regex 1 ---------------------------
 (?s)                    # Dot-All modifier (means dot . matches all chars, including newlines)
 (?<=                    # Lookbehind assertion
      \\ begin                # Literal escape + 'begin'
      \{ document \}          # Literal '{' + 'document' + '}'
 )
 (?P<checktext>          # (1 start), Python style named capture group
      .*                      # Greedy dot, match as many char's possible until end of string
 )                       # (1 end)

 ## Regex 2 ---------------------------
 (                       # (1 start), Open TAG
      \< \w+ \>               # Literal '<' + many words + '>'
 )                       # (1 end)
 (?P<checktext>          # (2 start), Python style named capture group
      .*                      # Greedy dot, match as many non-newline char's possible until end of line or string
 )                       # (2 end)
 (                       # (3 start), Close TAG
      \< / \w+ \>             # Literal '<' + '/' + many words + '>'
 )                       # (3 end)
```